# Python: Nested list comprehension / Flatten, no access in transform to outer list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension, nested-loops

(I Hope this is not a duplicate, but other questions are too many and badly named to find if so...)

(Tested in Python > 3, Solution - if any - must work in >= 2.7)

Assuming we have a list:

```
l = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

We attempt to flatten it using the standard list comprehension method:

```
[v for sl in l for v in sl] == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Output:

```
True
```

We then attempt:

```
[(v, s1[0]) for sl in l for v in sl]
```

Which causes:

```
NameError: name 's1' is not defined
```

Why does this happen?
Isn't `s1` supposed to be accessible given that the for loops are evaluated as the loop should be evaluated as:

```
[<expression> for <outer> in <list> for <inner> in <outer>]
```

Or in other words:

```
r = []
for <outer> in <list>:
   for <inner> in <outer>:
      r.append(<inner>)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are mixing up the names `sl` ("ess-ell") vs `s1` ("ess-one").

As an addendum, you should consider switching to a programmer-specific font which emphasizes the differences between otherwise potentially ambiguous characters. One popular option is [Source Code Pro](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Code+Pro).

Comment: Now I feel REALLY stupid :/ I'm actually using `Source Code Pro` in sublime... I guess I was too hasty.

Comment: I voted myself to close it now as well - hopefully I can forget this ever happened ;)